# Cordova keyboard changes layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

So I'm making my first Cordova app and I'm trying to create a simple login form. The thing is, when I click an input element, the keyboard pops up. For some reason this makes my whole layout change completely, while it isn't even close to being complicated.

Anyone knows why this occurs?

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
        https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
    Some notes:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:; connect-src https://ikleeralles.nl:*">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app-screen">
            <div id="result"></div>
            <form>
                <label for="username">Gebruikersnaam:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
                <label for="password">Wachtwoord:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                <button type="submit" id="submitForm" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
            </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/post.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:https://pastebin.com/vDSyqHSu

[image: Working well]

[image: when keyboard shows]

Comment: need to see code please

Comment: @Dan I added my code

Comment: Could you add the CSS part too?

Comment: @CTravel I added a pastebin link to the CSS. (It didn't fit in the post anymore)

Comment: @P.Yntema have you tried `position:relative;` instead of `position:absolute;` on `.app-screen`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the problem is in `min-aspect-ratio: 1/1`. Without the keyboard, the aspect ratio is different. Change the rules inside this media query or try to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because on line 20, you have to actually put:

```
body div.app-screen div.result form {

}
```

instead of:

```
.appscreen {

}
```